# How does AEM jar creates all the bundles?

Tags: java, jar, content-management-system, aem

I have this AEM 6.2 jar and when I try to execute this jar, it creates all the required files and folder and creates all the bundles under /launchpad/felix directory.

Now if I delete or rename a bundle e.g. I renamed bundle272 to bundle272aaa; try to execute the jar again, it removed bundle bundle272 from the directory.

If I copy this jar to some other location and try to execute it I am able to see bundle272 back at /launchpad/felix location.

Why is this happening?

Comment: What is your goal here? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the goal is a bit different. I was trying to understand the impact of one bundle on other bundles but got into this problem.

Comment: You do not need to delete bundles on the file system. Just go to http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles and stop a bundle. In short: Bundles provide functionality in the form of OSGi services. Other bundles can "consume" those OSGi services. One bundle could provide an email service while another bundle uses this service to send emails. If you would stop the email bundle the other bundle would not be able to send emails anymore. This is in very short terms how bundles relate to each other. (Obviously, there is much more to it but too much for a comment).

Comment: this I understand. my problem comes after the bundles are resolved.
I have an OSGI Bundle A and Bundle B.Bundle B is dependent on Bundle A.Both Bundle B and Bundle A are in active state.
Now I need to understand the impact of below scenarios on Bundle B
1) I have stopped Bundle A, what would happen to Bundle B.
2) I have uninstalled Bundle A. What would happen to Bundle B.
3) I have stopped Bundle A, Then I stopped Bundle B and now I am trying to resolve B from installed state.
4) I have uninstalled Bundle A, Then I stopped Bundle B and now I am trying to resolve B from installed state.

Comment: I guess you should create a new question. To put it short: If you stop a bundle other bundles depend on the depending bundles will either stay active or change to state "resolved" or "installed". Which state those bundles end up in depends on a few things.

Answer (score 1):

The AEM jar (archive) contains all those files. When you just copy the AEM jar and run it, it will extract all of those files (including the bundles) into the `crx-quickstart` directory.

Comment: Yes. this is what I thought but are you saying, it extracts only the first time?

Comment: also, I tried to check all the jars files from which it creates a bundle, I could not locate all those files in the aem jar

Comment: It depends. As far as I can tell some files are always overwriten (like `sling.properties`) and files like the bundles might not be extracted everytime. Probably to not slow down startup time too much.

Comment: this is what I figured but wanted if someone could confirm. also not being able to see all the jars inside that jar also bugged me a little.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a great question. The bundles you see inside crx-quickstart/launchpad/felix folder are just persisted as cache. The bundles are actually in the crx repository at different locations in install folders.

Apache Sling uses [JCR Installer](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/jcr-installer-provider.html) to install these bundles from different locations on the repository. This is the reason why your osgi jars are deployed to AEM if you put them in install folder like /apps/geometrixx/install.

Apache Sling also provides a different installer called as [File installer](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/file-installer-provider.html) which stores the bundles & configurations on disk.

I am guessing that JCR installer is implemented by inheriting File Installer, and that's why all bundles are written to disk but even if you rename or delete they are restored back on disk. I am writing this as a guess because I can't look into the source code and validate at this moment but this is what is most probably happening under the hood.

Comment: they are not restored back even if I restart the jar. Only when I copy the jar to some other place and then start it or delete the launchpad folder completely, then it puts all the file there.